# Adding network delay larger than ROS-rate periode?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I have a setup using Noetic where I want to emulate network delay with netimpair (which in itsself utilizes tc and netem) between two nodes.

A talker publishes current time at a rate of 10 and a subscribing listener calculates the delay. Additionally, for debugging purposes, I print the time periode since the last reception (last message callback) to the console. Netimpair is acting to the  publishing side of the setup, I checked the port using rosnode info.

Everything works as expected until I set the delay to a value > 1/rate (i.e. 100 ms). When I set the delay to, e.g., 110 ms, the following can be observed:

- The measured delay increases periodically in steps of 10 ms from message to message until it resets at 200 ms (110; 120; 130; ... 200; 110; ...).
- The delay between receptions of the 200 ms and 110 ms messages is close to zero, meaning that two messages are received at the same time.
- The delay between any other msg receptions is 110 ms (which is slower than the messages are actually sent, but on average with the zero-delay message, this corresponds to a rate of 10)
- No messages are lost if the queue is not set to 1

I am suspecting that the behavior stems from the way rostcp is handling messages, but so far I lag deeper understanding and can't explain this unexpected behavior. It seems like when a delayed TCP packet has not been sent yet, ROS just packs another message onto the packet in the delay queue.

Can somebody explain this or, even more appreciated, give a hint on how to achieve the expected delay independently of the rosrate? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414248/adding-network-delay-larger-than-ros-rate-periode?/) by [phikre](https://answers.ros.org/users/144269/phikre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's possible you're seeing Nagle's algorithm at work.

See #q360038 for a Q&A which discusses the various transport hint options you could use to disable it.

> It seems like when a delayed TCP packet has not been sent yet, ROS just packs another message onto the packet in the delay queue.

from what you describe: this is not ROS, but your TCP/IP network stack.

ROS just asks the OS to take care of handling the network side of things. There's nothing special here.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2023-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phikre](https://answers.ros.org/users/144269/phikre/) on 2023-04-12**:
Thanks a lot for the quick help, this was exactly the issue! I was spending quite some time to figure this out.
In rospy, the solution is to set tcp_nodelay=True when creating the subscriber, which deactivates Nagle's algo.